# Shiny navbarPage combined with fluidRow

Tags: r, shiny, fluid

I'm having some trouble with setting out the layout of my shiny app. After trying a couple of different options the one to work the best for me was the navbarPage. Although, I managed to solve the majority of my problems(with the help of stackoverflow) I'm stuck in one.
Basically, I have a table that has many columns and it ends up always larger than the wellPanel that contains the table.

Below is some code to illustrate the problem:

```
require(shiny)
require(shinythemes)

side_width <- 5

sidebar_panel <-
  sidebarPanel(
    width = side_width,
    radioButtons("Radio1",
                 label = h4("Radio label 1"),
                 choices = list("Europe" = "EU", 
                                "USA" = "US"), 
                               selected = "EU"),
hr()
br()

    radioButtons("Radio 2", 
                 label = h4("Radio label 2"),
                 choices = list("Annual" = 1, "Monthly" = 12), 
                             selected = 1)

  )

main_panel <- mainPanel(
    width = 12 - side_width,


                     wellPanel(

                     h5(helpText("Figure 1: ..."))
                               ), 

                     wellPanel(
                       h5(helpText("Table 1: ..."))
                              ),

                     wellPanel(
                       h5(helpText("Table 2: ..."))
                               ),

                     wellPanel(
                              fluidRow(
                              column(12,

                                h5(helpText("Table 3: ..."))
                                    )
                                 )

                       )
)

# user interface
ui <- shiny::navbarPage("testing shiny", 

  tabPanel("Tab1",
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebar_panel,
    mainPanel = main_panel,
    position = "left")
           ),

  tabPanel("Tab2",
    verbatimTextOutput("summary")
            ),

  tags$style(type="text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"),
  theme=shinytheme("cosmo"),
  position ="fixed-top"

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When you run the code you will see the current layout. All would be fine if it wasn't for that massive wide table 3 which half of it is always out of the wellPanel.

My question is is it possible to extend the wellPanel to the left so it occupies the entire width of the layout?

Any pointers are highly appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fluidRow and column functions don't do anything *inside* the wellPanel/mainPanel - you want to put this particular wellPanel as its own fluidRow separate from the sidebar layout.

Additionally, if your table is being made in the DT package, you can add scrollX=TRUE to the render options so that it'll add a scroll bar if the table is too big to fit.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinythemes)

side_width <- 5

# user interface
ui <- navbarPage(
  "testing shiny",
  tabPanel("Tab1",
    sidebarLayout(position = "left",
      sidebarPanel(width = side_width,
        radioButtons("Radio1",
          label = h4("Radio label 1"),
          choices = list("Europe" = "EU",
                         "USA" = "US"),
          selected = "EU"),
        hr(),
        br(),
        radioButtons("Radio 2",
          label = h4("Radio label 2"),
          choices = list("Annual" = 1, "Monthly" = 12),
          selected = 1)),
      mainPanel(
        width = 12 - side_width,
        wellPanel(
          h5(helpText("Figure 1: ..."))
        ),        
        wellPanel(
          h5(helpText("Table 1: ..."))
        ),
        wellPanel(
          h5(helpText("Table 2: ..."))
        )
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
        column(12,
            wellPanel(
               h5(helpText("Table 3: ..."))
            )
        )
    )
  ),

  tabPanel("Tab2",
           verbatimTextOutput("summary")),

  tags$style(type = "text/css", "body {padding-top: 70px;}"),
  theme = shinytheme("cosmo"),
  position = "fixed-top"

)
```

Comment: thank you very much for sorting this one out. It was driving me crazy. I think I now understand better the fluidrow and column functions. Also the way I had the code organized probably didn’t help out. I have arranged it in the classical way. Cheers

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, I found that particular code-organization unnecessary - using the traditional way is a little easier to debug :) 

For future reference, you can skip the whole 'sidebar-layout' segment in the future and just use [custom grid layout](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html#grid-layout) for more flexibility (i.e. possibly doing a three-column layout!)